# Concept of engine or mountable engine in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

In rails there seems to be a quite popular concept of engines even for things that are not stand-alone plugins but rather tiny contained web apps running in a web application.

I know grails has plugins the supplement the main application but I am wondering if grails can have sub-applications. For example you have a main application but then want a forum sub-application that simply uses the auth & auth models from the main application so that it does not need its own.

Is there any documentation or some basic concept tutorials on the engine concept for Grails?

Essentially I want to have a small main application that deals with auth & auth and some management but get all my other features to be sub-applications like splitting out forum, news, store, blog, etc but that all rely on the auth & auth of the main application. (making for a more modular grails app)

Thanks

Comment: but what the difference between 'plugin' and 'engine' at this case?

Comment: my knowledge with grails plugins is rather thin hence the question. If I were to just separate a simple part of a site like a forum to its own plugin does it just work the same way? I can just access the host models/methods without going through some long process of attaching the two? Most Plugins I notice for grails are things like authentication which binds to things to make things happen in the host application. Rails mountable engines tend to be standalone web apps that don't really push functionality to the host just use what the host provides (a little basic in description)

Answer (score 0):

Grails plugins are conceptually very similar to Rails Engines. The Grails plugin system can certainly be used to create a reusable component as you describe. You can embed all kinds of functionality into a Grails plugin including domain classes, controllers, UrlMappings, and views -- most things you would put into an application can be put into a plugin and it will be merged into whatever applications use that plugin.

There is a somewhat old blog post describing this approach [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html). The Grails user guide also has a detailed [chapter on plugins](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html).